# how to store culture name in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to develop a multilingual website, the problem that I have just to store the culture name in the database (for all the other data I'm using resource file)and I have to call it (culture name) from the view using dropdown list. Does anybody has an idea or examples?

Comment: What you want to do exactly? You want to store cultures in database and bind them to dropdown?

Comment: yes that's the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your point make Culture table with Id, culture code and Culture Name columns. Store culture code i.e. nl-NL and culture Name i.e. Dutch.

Then fetch them from db and create a list of it and bind them to dropdown. Bind culture code as value and culture name as Text of select dropdown. Use `SelectListItem` to do so like below:

```
this.ViewBag.Cultures = new SelectListItem(context.Cultures.Select(x=> new{ Id = x.CultureCode, Name = x.CultureName}), "Id", "Name").ToList();
```

Then on front end use dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropdownList("Cultures", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewBag.Cultures, "Select Culture")
```

**Note:** Store only those languages which you want to show on front side i.e. on UI.

You can ask me apart from this if you have any trouble.